# Jquery mobile loading spinner not working, never goes away

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a problem with the jquery mobile. 
Loading spinner not working, and the square that's holding it never goes away. so there is always an empty box in the middle of the page. even after the page has finished loading.

the square's class is `(ui-loader ui-corner-all ui-body-a ui-loader-default)`
and here's the `div`

```
<div class="ui-loader ui-corner-all ui-body-a ui-loader-default">
     <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-loading">
     </span>
     <h1>
        loading
     </h1>
</div>
```

these are the css/js files i m using, i wrote nothing in them, they are all generated.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mob_css/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" /> <--mobile css-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mob_css/alumni.css" /><--my theme css-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mob_css/jquery.mobile.custom.structure.min.css" /><--no idea-->
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="mob_css/jquery.mobile.custom.theme.min.css" />--><--no idea-->
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="my.css" />--><--empty css-->
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script><--jquery-->
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script><--mobile jquery-->
<script src="js/jquery.mobile.custom.min.js"></script><--no idea-->
```

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me

```
$(".ui-loader").hide();
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`$.mobile.loading("hide")` has to used along with `setInterval` sometimes. Its not there in the API but it works. Try this.

```
var interval = setInterval(function () {
            $.mobile.loading('hide');
            clearInterval(interval);
        }, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
function loading(showOrHide) {
   setTimeout(function(){
    $.mobile.loading(showOrHide);
  }, 1000);//make 1 second interval 
}
```

Call from somewhere:-

```
loading('show');
//do some stuff
loading('hide');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell jQuery when to show / hide the loader. I use a global loading widget like this

```
$( document ).bind( 'mobileinit', function(){
  $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.text = "loading";
  $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.textVisible = false;
  $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.theme = "a";
  $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.html = "";
});
```

Then you can show it like this

```
$.mobile.loading("show");
```

and hide it like this

```
$.mobile.loading("hide");
```

Comment: $.mobile.loading("hide"); is working well but I am trying this code to hide after loading : 
jQuery(window).load(function () {  $.mobile.loading("hide"); });
and its not working

Answer (score -1):

Try this...
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("show", "Loading..."); or

$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("show", "Loading theme a...");

Comment: Try some explanation with your code. All on it's own, it's a bit "rough"